# ggplot2: Change legend symbol

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2, legend

I have plotted several lines and I am wondering how to change the symbol in the legend to go from the thin line to a full block.

I am trying to go from

[image: this] to [image: this]

(while using geom_line and not geom_bar)

Comment: Please show us the code and the sample data.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use function `guides()` and then with argument `override.aes=` set line `size=` (width) to some large value. To remove the grey area around the legend keys set `fill=NA` for `legend.key=` inside `theme()`.

```
df<-data.frame(x=rep(1:5,each=3),y=1:15,group=rep(c("A","B","C"),each=5))
ggplot(df,aes(x,y,color=group,fill=group))+geom_line()+
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 10)))+
  theme(legend.key=element_rect(fill=NA))
```

[image]

Answer (score 36):

Starting in **ggplot2_3.2.0**, you can choose which glyph you want displayed in the legend keys using the `key_glyph` argument in the `geom_*()`.

For example, you want to use rectangles instead of lines as your glyph.  In that case you can do

```
df = data.frame(x = rep(1:5, each=3),
                y = 1:15,
                group = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each=5))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, color=group) )+
    geom_line(key_glyph = "rect")
```

[image]

See `?draw_key` for a list of the current glyphs available.